# How to read Twitter statuses information from my app

Tags: android, twitter, status

I want to implement in my app one reader of twitter for a specific user , 
is it possible to read without login in to twitter . if it possible tell me the process. how can i achieve this. if it is not possible how to proceed .

i know how to post message on twitter, now i want read the message..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can.

Here's the [relevant API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/user_timeline)  You'll need to know the userid or the screen name of the user.